# Bean validation Java conditional

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

Right now I have a class `BaseSchedule`  It is used by 4 classes (composition).  I would like to validate in two use classes and not in the others.  I am a little stumped on how to do so.

My `BaseSchedule` looks like the following:

```
@Embeddable
@DatesStartBeforeEnd(start = "startDateTime", end = "endDateTime")
public class BaseSchedule implements Serializable {

    private Date startDateTime;

    private Date endDateTime;
}
```

I would like to check to make sure that the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` are not null when I go to persist the data to my database.  Normally I would provide a `@NotNull` to each of the fields.

```
public class TimeSlot implements Scheduleable {
  @Embedded
  private BaseSchedule schedule;
}
```

But... in the case of my `TimeSlotTemplate` I do not want validation as I know it will be null.

```
public class TimeSlotTemplate extends SchedulableClassTemplateEvent {
    @Embedded
    private BaseSchedule schedule;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Hibernate Validator as your BV provider, one solution might be to use a custom [default group sequence provider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2886).

For this to work, your `BaseSchedule` object would have to know about the "role" it currently has, e.g. by passing an enum with values such as `SlotSchedule`, `TemplateSchedule` etc. to its constructor. Depending on the role a group sequence provider could then determine the sequence to validate and return a sequence which does not contain the `@NotNull` constraints if the role is `TemplateSchedule`.

Not that this approach requires that you use the default sequence during JPA lifecycle validation.

Comment: I looked at this solution once.  I could not figure it out but... I will give it another shot.  It slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done using the @PrePersist Annotation.

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist(){
 if(isPerformNullableCheck()){
        // check for null values and raise an error if invalid
 }
}
```

in your TimeSlotTemplate, you can set the performNullableCheck property to false...

Another way might be to add a class into the hierarchy.
BaseSchedule contains the properties needed and e.g. ValidatedSchedule (extends BaseSchedule) overrides those and performs the notnull checks. Don't know whether this works or not. Also this would probably not be the best solution for your problem..?